# Installing ESI on Mac osx or windows (for localhost testing)

Tags: apache, include, akamai, esi

Hope some server side gurus can answer this one or point me in the right direction.

We use Akamai in our corporate website setting. And therefore there's extensive use of 'ESI' files.

I have 'mamp' installed on my Mac osx with bitnami's package. How can I add esi capability on top of my apache?

A lot of googling suggest that perhaps squid proxy or varnish proxy can allow this functionality. Would this be right? Can I use these in a 'local host' situation when there's no domain name and no live open-to-publi stuff, just my own machine?

Appreciate any insight. Maybe I'm googling this wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use Varnish for this. While Varnish does not support all of the custom tags that you can do with Akamai's ESI handling, straight-forward standard ESI tags will work.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use more of the ESI language than just includes (HTTP headers, ESI variables, etc.), I would recommend using Akamai's [ESI Test Server](http://www.akamai.com/html/support/esi.html) on a local VM.